# passing data from antdesign table row to modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd, ant-design-pro

I have a table in which each row has a button that would send a `DELETE` request to delete that row's data from database:

```
{
    title: '',
    render: (record) => {
        return (
            <Button icon={<DeleteOutlined />} style={{color:'#1890ff', border:'solid 0px'}} onClick={() => showModal(record)}
            >
            </Button>
        ) 
    }
},
```

Here I'm trying to pass the `record` data when clicking on the button to a modal. To do that I created a `useState` hook that would store my table row's data and then I wanted to pass the data to a modal:

```
const [modalTaskId, setModalTaskId] = useState();
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
const showModal = (record) => {
    setModalTaskId(record);
    setVisible(true);

};
```

This is my modal:

```
<Modal
    visible={visible}
    onOk={() =>{handleOk()}}
    confirmLoading={confirmLoading}
    onCancel={handleCancel}
>
    <p>{modalText}</p>
</Modal>
```

And let's say I want to log the `modalTaskId` when clicking ok on modal:

```
const handleOk = async () => {
    console.log('modalTaskId: ', modalTaskId)
}
```

But it logs empty for me! So how can I pass data from my table's row to my modal and then use that data when clicking on modal's ok button?

Comment: any update on if you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

[Here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xezlcb?file=index.js)

Essentially, depending on the scope of your `columns` object, you can wrap them as a return value in a function that captures the context of your `showModal` handler.

```js
const getColumns(showModal) { 
  return [{
    title: "Buttons", 
    dataIndex: 'arbitrary', 
    render: (text, record) => 
      <Button onClick={showModal}>Open Modal</Button>
  }, ...]
}

...

// Usage
<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={getColumns(showModal)} />
```

Note that this may not be the most performant solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the first, set the Initial value for your `modalTaskId`.

```
const [modalTaskId, setModalTaskId] = useState();
```

Then, remove `onOk`, You can control your visibility by `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (visible) console.log(modalTaskId);
}, [visible])
```

Comment: my modal has an "ok" button that confirms my action. I want to log my row's data when user clicks on "ok" button not when the modal is visible which basically means I need to log the data with `handleOk`